# concatenating variable onto a value in an object

Tags: javascript, object, key-value

I trying to concatenate a value onto the end of another value (`rollno`) in an object. The value should be a number (or number in a string) that increases by one each time. (Alternatively adding a new property with a number that increases by 1 would be just as good). I've tried various ways, below is the closest I've managed to get. The code only works once then breaks.

How can I alter my code to achieve this or am I going about this the wrong way ?

```
<button id='button'>add roll number</button>

student = {

name : "David Rayy", 
sclass : "VI", 
rollno : 12
};

function addRollno() {
    var num

    student.rollno = student.rollno + ' ' + (student.rollno +1);

    console.log(student.rollno);
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', addRollno, false);
```

Comment: Use `student.rollno++` or `student.rollno += 1` to increment the number by one each time (instead of `student.rollno = student.rollno + ' ' + (student.rollno +1)`)

Answer (score 0):

To add the next incrementing number to the `rollno` property, you'd need to store the last `rollno` used, increment that by one and add to the `rollno`;

```
<button id='button'>add roll number</button>
<script>
student = {
    name : "David Rayy", 
    sclass : "VI", 
    lastRollno : 12,
    rollno : 12
};

function addRollno() {
    var num

    student.rollno = student.rollno + ' ' + (++student.lastRollno);

    console.log(student.rollno);
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', addRollno, false);
</script>
```

To only increment the `rollno` by 1 and not store any previous `rollno` values you could just increment it by 1;

```
<button id='button'>add roll number</button>
<script>
student = {
    name : "David Rayy", 
    sclass : "VI", 
    rollno : 12
};

function addRollno() {
    var num

    student.rollno = ++student.rollno;

    console.log(student.rollno);
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', addRollno, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shorthand [Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators) operator `+=`

```
student.rollno +=1;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jBEdP/4/)